# Count of events in aggregate query since row specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to analyse the number of shots, hits and events by target using SQL Server 2008.  If a shot hits the target, there is the chance of an event.  I'd like to know the date of the last event, and how many shots have hit the target since the last event.

My input tables are somewhat like this:

```
TargetList
Site_Code   Target_Code WEIGHT Client
SiteA       00001       1      ClientName
SiteA       00002       1      ClientName
SiteA       00003       1      ClientName
SiteA       00004       1      ClientName

Attempts
ID         Start_Time               Client      Target_Code
ID-0001    2017-01-24 01:35:30.000  ClientName  00001
ID-0002    2017-01-24 02:35:30.000  ClientName  00001
ID-0003    2017-01-24 03:35:30.000  ClientName  00001
ID-0004    2017-01-24 04:35:30.000  ClientName  00001
ID-0005    2017-01-24 05:35:30.000  ClientName  00001
ID-0006    2017-01-24 06:35:30.000  ClientName  00001
ID-0007    2017-01-24 07:35:30.000  ClientName  00001
ID-0008    2017-01-24 08:35:30.000  ClientName  00001
ID-0009    2017-01-24 09:35:30.000  ClientName  00001
ID-0010    2017-01-24 10:35:30.000  ClientName  00001
ID-0011    2017-01-24 11:35:30.000  ClientName  00001
ID-0012    2017-01-24 12:35:30.000  ClientName  00001

Hits
ID      AttemptID    Datetime                 ClientName   TargetCode  HitType
HT-0001 ID-0002      2017-01-24 02:35:30.000  ClientName   00001       Z5
HT-0002 ID-0003      2017-01-24 03:35:30.000  ClientName   00001       A1
HT-0003 ID-0004      2017-01-24 04:35:30.000  ClientName   00001       B5
HT-0004 ID-0006      2017-01-24 06:35:30.000  ClientName   00001       Z5
--Most recent Event below
HT-0005 ID-0008      2017-01-24 16:35:30.000  ClientName   00001       Z5
--4 Hits since the last Z5 event
HT-0006 ID-0009      2017-01-24 09:35:30.000  ClientName   00001       A1
HT-0007 ID-0010      2017-01-24 10:35:30.000  ClientName   00001       A1
HT-0008 ID-0011      2017-01-24 11:35:30.000  ClientName   00001       A1
HT-0009 ID-0012      2017-01-24 12:35:30.000  ClientName   00001       A1
```

And my intended output:

```
SiteCode    TargetCode    CountOfAttempts    CountofHits    LastEvent                   HitsSinceLastEvent
SiteA       00001         12                 9              2017-01-24 16:35:30.000   4
```

So far my query is:

```
select bp.Site_Code 'Site'
    , bp.Target_Code 'Target'
    , COUNT(ca.id) 'Count of Attempts'
    , COUNT(htt.id) 'Count of Hits'
    , lst.[Last Event] 'Last Event'

from (select Site_Code, Target_Code
        from TargetList t
        where t.WEIGHT > 0 
            and Client = 'ClientName') as bp 

    left join Attempts ca on bp.Target_Code = ca.Target_Code and ca.START_TIME > '20170130' and ca.Client = 'ClientName'

    Left join HitInformation htt on htt.Attemptid = ca.id

    left join (select ht.TargetCode 'Target'
                , max(ht.datetime) 'Last Event' 
            from HitInformation ht 
            where rc.Client = 'ClientName' 
                and ht.DATETIME > '20170101' 
                and ht.HitType = 'Z5' 
            group by ht.TargetCode
                ) as lst on lst.TargetCode= bp.Target_Code

group by bp.Site_Code, bp.Target_Code, lst.[Last Event]
order by COUNT(ht.id)desc
```

I've used a subquery to determine the last instance of Z5 hit, but I'm stumped how to get the number of hits since the last event.

My google efforts have included variations of 'find totals since event sql server' and 'total by row specific date sql server', but I'm not turning up anything relevant.

I thank you in advance for any help that you can give.

Comment: why would there be any hits after the lasthit? i don't understand this.

Comment: @vkp Apologies for the wording.  Target can be hit many times over.  Each time it is hit, there is a chance of an event.  Events will happen multiple times over the course of a target's life.  I'd like to know how long since the last event, and how many hits have not triggered an event.  Error corrected in output names.